# Generate the same object file with a native compiler and a cross compiler

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gcc, arm

I'm trying to use a cross compiler running on Ubuntu to compile some Raspberry Pi code. I have already tested the executable and it works fine, but comparing that executable to the one generated by the native compiler (gcc on Raspberry Pi) I see there are some differences between the binary files.

### Setup

The native compiler is `gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0` running on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). The cross compiler is `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0` running on Ubuntu 18.04.4 (Bionic Beaver).

I tried to make sure that the cross compiler is using the same compilation flags as the one on the Pi uses by default:

- `marm` to generate code that runs in ARM state (instead of Thumb)
- `march=armv6`
- `mfpu=vfp`
- `O0` and I turned off the optimizations to make sure nothing "funny" is going on

### What I have tried

I wrote the most bare-bones C code I could think of:

```
int main() {}
```

And then compiled it into assembly using Unified Assembly Language syntax. Both compilers generated the exact same assembly (except for the `.ident` line, but that one doesn't matter):

```
    .arch armv6
    .eabi_attribute 28, 1
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 2
    .eabi_attribute 30, 6
    .eabi_attribute 34, 1
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .arch armv6
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu vfp
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    str fp, [sp, #-4]!
    add fp, sp, #0
    mov r3, #0
    mov r0, r3
    add sp, fp, #0
    @ sp needed
    ldr fp, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

I then tried something else: I just built the object file before linking it to any shared libraries, but even then there will be differences between the native and cross compiled files. Therefore, it's not an issue of the installed libraries being different between Raspbian and Ubuntu.

### Problem

If I compile this assembly code using the native compiler and the cross compiler, I will get different executables even though they function the same way.

### Question

Even though it's not a big deal since both executables work as expected (they do nothing and return 0) I would like to know:

- Why does this happen?
- Is it a matter of using slightly different versions of gcc (8.3.0 vs 8.4.0)?
- Or are these differences inherent to the operating system that runs the compiler?
- And is it possible to use a cross compiler to build the exact same executable as a native compiler would? Even when the code is very big and complex?

Comment: Given that it's the same assembly, it's definitely not your compiler. Could be your linker or the options passed to the linker, or more likely library versions. You did not say what the differences were.

Comment: Thanks @Jester. You're right, it's not the compiler but another part of the toolchain. I tried to check what happens before the linking stage, so I just generated the object file for my `main` function. The results are still different.

Comment: You could use `objdump` to see what the differences actually are (try `--disassemble` and `--full-contents`).  Once you see what's actually different, the reason may become obvious.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thank you! Using `--full-contents` I see that the `main.o` files only differ on the contents of section `.comment`; they specify the OS that was running gcc, which is either Raspbian or Ubuntu. But comparing the executables after linking to other libraries, I see there are many differences beyond the `.comment` section.

Comment: Did you link against identical libc versions?  If not, perhaps different symbol version stuff happened?  glibc uses some symbol-versioning tricks.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes, when I was installing everything on Ubuntu I just downloaded `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi`. But checking the specific versions, I see that on Raspbian I have `Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+rpi1`, but on Ubuntu I have `Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2`.

Comment: we just covered this topic today.  there is no reason to expect any two compilers even the same version built separately with possibly different options, to produce the same code.  then there is the topic of C libraries which are not necessarily part of the toolchain and here again not expected to match even if both are gnu but possibly different versions.  linker script which is often part of the C library but not really a compiler thing.  basically there is no reason to expect these binaries to match.  and apparently they dont thus the question.

Comment: some compilers embed dates into the binary so even the same code same machine same day different times can have that small difference.  Some embed file paths, so same project same machine same day, product is in a different directory, binary will vary both in comparison and possibly size.  But as mentioned above you need to disect the binaries to find where the differences are, different gcc, binutils and/or glibc versions the expectation is the binaries dont match beyond dates and file paths.

Comment: even more fun I dont remember if it was borland or zortech, wouldnt zero out the memory used to build the project, so if you had a string of say 5 characters that the tool aligned to say 8, the extra three bytes would be whatever was in memory from the programs prior to running this tool, you would get various sized chunks of other stuff, sometimes recognizable text from when you ran a text editor if some program/file at some point in the past,  same tool same source same day, could never get the binaries to match...fun stuff...they are much better about that now...

Comment: Thanks @old_timer, from your answer I gather that the best I can do is to make sure that the functional parts of the executable, whether it's built by the Pi or a cross compiler. But there's nothing I can (easily) do about things such as embedded metadata, right?

Comment: well if you want to compare the files then you can use tools like readelf and objdump objcopy to pull out the executable and data portions and compare those leaving the metadata and some debug stuff behind but some folks embed stuff in their programs I dont use it often enough to remember (well I never do it is someone elses code where is see it) that you can error out from a fuction with the name of the file and line number and that is actually in the binary/data not metadata and that can vary by directory I think.  but still.

Comment: you can objcopy to an srec or ihex or something and try to compare those.  Now the title question is about objects and the body of the question appears to be a linked program you can focus on the objects of your sources (compared to library stuff you link in magically from somewhere in the system) and see how they compare using similar tools, you can try to strip out some of that metadata and debug stuff too.

Comment: I dont know what your goal is if it is just to cross compile which you should be able to do and have a binary that works, or if there is a need to get identical binaries for some reason.  If there is some reason I would offer perhaps you have a buildbot that builds the master version of the binaries instead of trying to build from two places, but I dont know the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think I should've been more clear: now that you've explained this, I don't expect the binaries to be identical. What I would like is to generate binaries that only differ on non-functional stuff. It'd be even better if I can guarantee that the cross-compiler is using the exact same libraries as the Pi does. That way, when I write code and stumble into problems, at least I can rule out the possibility of using the wrong version of a library or the compiler generating code that is somehow incompatible with the target architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker may add a "build id" to the binary. creating a spurious "difference".

Try compiling them with **`-Wl,--build-id=none`**.

There's also the `.comment` section, which contains info about the version of the compiler and the platform it runs on. You can strip it afterwards with **`strip -R .comment your_binary`**.

I'm not aware of any way to let gcc not create that `.comment` section, other than using an ad-hoc [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#Miscellaneous-Commands) (which may not be practical):

```
SECTIONS { /DISCARD/ : { *(.comment) } } INSERT BEFORE .bss
```

Stupid example:

```
cc -Wall -o no_comment \
  -include stdio.h -xc - <<<'int main(){printf("test\n");}' \
  -xnone -Wl,-T /dev/fd/7 /dev/fd/7 7<<<'SECTIONS { /DISCARD/ : { *(.comment) } } INSERT BEFORE .bss' \
  -Wl,--build-id=none
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion but I still see many differences between the files. I'm thinking the issue is with the version of the libraries installed on Ubuntu, as @PeterCordes commented.

Comment: I'll leave the answer on for reference, though.

Comment: I tried the example you posted in the end but I get this error: `/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: .ldata not found for insert`
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @David look at the default linker script (with `ld --verbose`) and find another place to insert your extra commands. `.bss`  should work instead of `.ldata`. I've added a link to the GNU ld manual -- read it ;-)

Comment: thank you for the reference! And yes! `.bss` worked, it was part of my default linker script.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, @user414777 is right.

And also the

> `.ident` line, but that one doesn't matter

... actually ends up in the binary:
try `readelf -p .comment a.out`

Comment: Thank you @kisch, you're right, I just verified it with `readelf` as you suggested and the comment is part of the executable file. This is good to know.